# Slider/slideshow HTML Code Without JavaScript/CSS

Tags: html, slider, slideshow

I'd like to add a slider (like this: http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) on my Wordpress.com blog on the sidebar without changing my theme. However, I'm not allowed to use Javascript or CSS. Is there a way I can write this?

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: @DavidThomas Wordpress.com prevents me from using Javascript or Flash (though I can work around it for Flash), and I need to buy an upgrade in order to use CSS.

Comment: Such a thing is not possible in html alone. You could build a page then add it into your blog via iframes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an HTML editor which does not allow you to write your own javascript.  Editors which provide "themes" are easy to use, but canNot guard/sustain its "theme" properties/appearances against javascript and CSS code.  Therefore, most internet editors do not allow it.  They offers only certain objects which the "theme" can process.

Since much of the theme is defined in CSS properties, it would be nice if the theme creator would provide documentation and allow the user to enter CSS which would alter the actual theme declarations.  JavaScript and CSS could easily render the theme inoperative.  And what seems to be "functional" CSS and/or JavaScript code could suddenly disrupt the theme due to any alteration.  Supplying ability and documentation for either would require theme versions to be retained so that the chosen theme could continue to operate properly with your JavaScript and CSS.  In other words... If the editor provider tweaked the theme, then your functional theme/CSS/JavaScript combination could easily be rendered inoperative and call-in complaints would arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use jQuery, then a flash object would be the only option IMO.

Comment: Do you know how I could use Flash to create one?